# How to save result row set in Pentaho variable?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Inside the job I have several transformations. In particular, one transformation looks up filenames from some directory. *'Copy rows to result'* is used and next transformation in the master job is using those rows(filenames). After several steps in the master job another transformation needs these filenames.

How could I access those values from inside the last transformation (given that last transformation is preceded by several other steps in the job) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just do the lookup again?

Comment: because steps that follow lookup would change the contents of the folder but I need the initial values

Comment: You could output the list to a file before the contents change and read that later. If you really want to use variables you would have to create a loop and call it for each value of the variable which I think would be slower

Answer (score 0):

Use the get file names and pass it to copy rows to results. Let this be transformation_1. Next create a job say job_1, where all other transformations  process/use the files/file names which will be then become another job, say job_2.

So flow will be as follows :

Job_2
Start -> transformation_1 -> job_1 (tick copy rows to parameter and execute for each row options in job_1 advanced options)

Job_1 
start -> all transformations that use/process the file/file names.

transformation_1
get file names -> copy rows to result